# Filter JSON array leaving all MAX values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

Here it is original array,

```
var dates = 
[ { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' },
  { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' },
  { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' },
  { user_id: '1', week_number: '3', amount: '100' },
  { user_id: '3', week_number: '3', amount: '100' } ]
```

**Update**

First I have tried to sort array by highest `week_number` values with:

```
var x = dates.sort(function (itemA, itemB) {
  return itemA.week_number < itemB.week_number; 
  });
```

to get :

```
[ { user_id: '1', week_number: '3', amount: '100' },
  { user_id: '3', week_number: '3', amount: '100' },
  { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' },
  { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' },
  { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' } ]
```

and then use.filter to get

```
[ { user_id: '1', week_number: '3', amount: '100' },
  { user_id: '3', week_number: '3', amount: '100' },]
```

Later I found `reduce` method but it only returns an object with highest `week_number` value.

```
var max = dates.reduce(function(prev, current) {
  return (prev.week_number > current.week_number) ? prev : current
    })
```

As you will see `.filter` will get the job done.

Many thanks for all answers you provided. You are the best!!!

Comment: than it should show array with objects that contains `'4'`

Comment: I mean, what if there only one item `week_number: '4'` and multiple `week_number: '3'` ?

Comment: There should be array with object that contains `week_number: 'max'`

Comment: if you can guarantee that the list is `week_number` sorted, then all you need to do is start a loop at the end, and break when the `week_number` changes.

Comment: you need not to sort the array, because you need just a single loop for getting the wantend objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map` method to get all the `week_number`.Get the largest from this array,now use this largest value in `filter` method to get the matching object

```js
var dates = [{
    user_id: '1',
    week_number: '2',
    amount: '100'
  },
  {
    user_id: '1',
    week_number: '2',
    amount: '100'
  },
  {
    user_id: '4',
    week_number: '4',
    amount: '100'
  },
  {
    user_id: '1',
    week_number: '2',
    amount: '100'
  },
  {
    user_id: '1',
    week_number: '3',
    amount: '100'
  },
  {
    user_id: '3',
    week_number: '3',
    amount: '100'
  }
]

var o = dates.map(function(item) {
  return +item.week_number;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return a - b
})[dates.length - 1]
console.log(o)
var m = dates.filter(function(elem) {
  return elem.week_number === o.toString();
})
console.log(m)
```

**EDIT**

The map function in above code is redundant,sorting the dates will give the object with greatest week_number, then filter can be used to get the desired result

```js
var dates = [{
    user_id: '1',
    week_number: '2',
    amount: '100'
  },
  {
    user_id: '1',
    week_number: '2',
    amount: '100'
  },
  {
    user_id: '4',
    week_number: '4',
    amount: '100'
  },
  {
    user_id: '1',
    week_number: '2',
    amount: '100'
  },
  {
    user_id: '1',
    week_number: '3',
    amount: '100'
  },
  {
    user_id: '3',
    week_number: '3',
    amount: '100'
  }
]

var o = dates.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.week_number - b.week_number
})[dates.length - 1]

var m = dates.filter(function(elem) {
  return elem.week_number === o.week_number;
})
console.log(m)
```

Comment: this won't work if there would be item `{ user_id: '4', week_number: '4', amount: '100' }` in the middle of array

Comment: Why `.map()`? The OP's original `.reduce()` would be better (with some repair). If you can assume the largest `week_number` is at the end, then the `.map()` is entirely superfluous, since you could just do `var o = dates[dates.length-1].week_number`

Comment: why not just take the last value of the array as max value. if the data is sorted by `week_number`, then no mapping is required.

Comment: @NinaScholz I agree map is not required at all

Comment: Why is a complex `.sort()` better than the original `.reduce()`? The time complexity of the `.reduce()` is much lower.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single loop approach by checking the `week_number` and replace the result set if necessary.

```js
var dates = [{ user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '3', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '3', week_number: '3', amount: '100' }],
    result = dates.reduce(function (r, o, i) {
        return !i || r[0].week_number < o.week_number
            ? [o]
            : r[0].week_number === o.week_number
                ? r.concat(o)
                : r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this won't work if there would be `{ user_id: '4', week_number: '4', amount: '100' }` as the last item

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, right, i thought the id should be respected.

Comment: anyway, it seems that the OP does not consider any other approaches

Answer (score 0):

`reduce` might not be the best tool for this task. Instead, a loop-style solution is probably better:

```
var maxWeek = 0;
var max = [];
dates.forEach(function(date) {
    const week = date.week_number;
    if (week > maxWeek) {
        maxWeek = week;
        max = [date];
    }
    else if (week === maxWeek) {
        max.push(date);
    }
});
```

Note: I haven't tested this code so I can't guarantee the absence of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

With `Array.sort()` function:

The initial example was extended with additional item:

```js
var dates = [{ user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '3', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '3', week_number: '3', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '4', week_number: '4', amount: '100' }],
    result = [];

dates.sort(function(a, b){ return +b.week_number - +a.week_number; });
result.push(dates[0]);
for (var i=2, len = dates.length; i<=len; i++) {
    if (dates[i].week_number != result[0].week_number) break;
    result.push(dates[i]);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var res = [], prev, max;
 for (var i = 0, len = dates.length; i < len; i++) {
   max = parseInt(dates[i].week_number);
   if (!res.length) {
    prev = max; res.push(dates[i]);
   } else if (prev === max) {
    res.push(dates[i]);
   } else if (max > prev) {
    prev = max; res.length = 0; res.push(dates[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that the list is sorted on `week_number`, it's just a simple reverse loop.

```js
var dates = [{ user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '3', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '3', week_number: '3', amount: '100' }];

var i = dates.length;
var last = dates[--i];
while (--i !== -1 && dates[i].week_number === last.week_number) {
}

var res = dates.slice(i+1);
console.log(res);
```

---

Or use `.reduceRight()`, though you don't get to halt the loop.

```js
var dates = [{ user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '3', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '3', week_number: '3', amount: '100' }];

var res = dates.reduceRight((a, obj) => 
  a.length && obj.week_number !== a[a.length-1].week_number ? a : [obj, ...a]
, []);

console.log(res);
```

---

However, if you can't rely on the sort order of the list, you then should use the `.reduce()` that you already wrote, and use its result in a `.filter()` operation.

```js
var dates = [{ user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '2', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '1', week_number: '3', amount: '100' }, { user_id: '3', week_number: '3', amount: '100' }];
 
var max = dates.reduce((p, c) => +p.week_number > +c.week_number ? p : c).week_number;
var res = dates.filter(d => d.week_number == max)

console.log(res);
```